# Get list of all tabs and exclude those that the active user cannot edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a little project where I call a function `getUserSheets` to get a list of all tabs except few, which works fine (see first Loop). But I want to take a step further by also excluding the tabs that the user cannot edit (attempt in second Loop). But when running the function test(), `Logger.log(mysheets)` returns `null`. I presume I'm not checking the condition properly.

Your help is appreciated.

```
function test() {

      // I use this function just to see what the Logger returns

        var mysheets = getUserSheets();
        Logger.log(mysheets);
    }
```

**CODE**:

```
function getUserSheets() {

    var cost = new Array()
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        var all = sheets[i];
        if (
            (all.getName() == "Instructions") ||
            (all.getName() == "Database") ||
            (all.getName() == "Permissions") ||
            (all.getName() == "Setup") ||
            (all.getName() == "Weeks")
        ) continue;

        // My attempt to check wether the user can edit the sheet
        var protections = sheets[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
        for (var j = 0; j < protections.length; j++) {
            var protection = protections[j];

            if (protection.canEdit()) {

                cost.push([sheets[i].getName()])
            }

            return cost
        }
    }
}
```

Note: all tabs have a SHEET protection,

**In brief**, I want to return all tabs and exclude those mentioned in the first Loop, and likewise I want to exclude the tabs that the active user cannot edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to return the array including the sheet name by excluding the sheet which cannot be edited.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, by `var protections = sheets[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];`, an error occurs at `protections.length`.
- About `return cost` in your script, in this case, 2nd for loop is finished at the 1st loop.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var all = sheets[i];
    if (
        (all.getName() == "Instructions") ||
        (all.getName() == "Database") ||
        (all.getName() == "Permissions") ||
        (all.getName() == "Setup") ||
        (all.getName() == "Weeks")
    ) continue;

    // My attempt to check wether the user can edit the sheet
    var protections = sheets[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
    for (var j = 0; j < protections.length; j++) {
        var protection = protections[j];

        if (protection.canEdit()) {

            cost.push([sheets[i].getName()])
        }

        return cost
    }
}
```

To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  var all = sheets[i];
  if (
    (all.getName() == "Instructions") ||
    (all.getName() == "Database") ||
    (all.getName() == "Permissions") ||
    (all.getName() == "Setup") ||
    (all.getName() == "Weeks")
  ) continue;
  var protection = all.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  if (protection.length == 1 && !protection[0].canEdit()) continue;
  cost.push([sheets[i].getName()]);
}
return cost;
```

#### Reference:

- [getProtections(type)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getprotectionstype)

Comment: Just for the sake of learning: is there a better way of writing the For Loop, because I see very often in your answers in this forum using map() or filter() or forEach()? Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: @Nabnub Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, unfortunately, about `a better way of writing the For Loop`, I couldn't understand about what you want. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But at this stackoverflow, there are a lot of sample scripts. So the helpful samples might be able to be found. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new question immediately. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var protections = sheets[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
```

assigns the first Class Protection object to `protections`  but this object doesn't include a length property ...

- so `protections.length` returns `undefined`
- so the `for` code block is not executed

Fix

Replace the above code line by

```
var protections = sheets[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
```

(remove `[0]`)

Comment: thank you for your input. I've tried this before posting the question, and it returns only the first sheet.

Comment: You are welcome. I see that you already accepted the answer by Tanaike, That is good (that answer also mentions the same as this one, but it also mentions other things to be fixed)